# can't use instance method in UIBezierPath()

Tags: swift

Suppose I want to draw a line in case 1, I can not use the methods in UIBezierPath() if I use the method in another line.

But I can use the methods if I add "." immediately after BezierPath() like case 2

***case 1***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.
}
```

[image]

***case 2***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let path = UIBezierPath().move(to: <#T##CGPoint#>)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure about the issue. Are you saying if you initialize a UIBezierPath (case 1) you then **cannot** use *.move(to:)* where the input is a CGPoint? Why? I can. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: I mean if you want xcode infer the methods of  UIBezierPath() after you enter the "." after "path", you can't get what you want. You can see the picture I added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the first two lines of your code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let path = UIBezierPath()
```

The first line (starting with `class`) begins the definition of a class named `ViewController`. The second line (starting with `let`) defines an instance property named `path`, and says that every time your program creates an instance of `ViewController`, it should initialize the `path` variable by evaluating the expression `UIBezierPath()`.

Then you're trying to write something like this:

```
path.move(to: .zero)
```

The problem is that you are trying to write that line directly in the class definition. You can't. The only things that you can put directly in a class definition are property and method definitions. You cannot put statements to be executed.

You have two alternatives. One is to finish initializing the property in some later method, for example in `viewDidLoad`. Julian J. Tejera's answer covers this.

Another way to do it is to initialize the property by executing a closure:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let path: UIBezierPath = {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 0))
        return path
    }()

}
```

Note that you cannot refer to any `ViewController` instance properties or methods in that closure, because `self` is not fully initialized when it runs.

Comment: how do you know there can be  two alternatives, by experience or by some documents?

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you need to invoke the method inside of a function, not inside of the class' declaration. Try the following:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        // Invoke method here
        path.
    }
}
```